# Hacer la media de tres valores de un arreglo en Java

Tags: java, array

Quiero obtener la media de tres notas introducidas en un arreglo:

Código:

```
System.out.println("\nIntroduca notas correspondientes(1-10)");         

for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{               
    do{
        System.out.print("Nota "+(j+1)+" : ");
        notas[j]=tecla.nextInt();   
        if(notas[j]<1 || notas[j]>10)
        {
            System.out.println("\nLa notas deben ir del 1 al 10, introduzca de nuevo");
        }
    }while(notas[j]<1 || notas[j]>10);                          
}                       
objAlumnos.setNotas(notas);
```

Pero tengo esa parte de código para introducir las notas, pero ahora no se como coger cada nota para sumarla y dividirla entre 3.

Comment: Y en donde tienes el error??? que código has hecho???

Comment: necesitas tener un variable que este fuera de los dos for que guarde la suma y despues del segundo for ir sumando los valores leidos que si cumplen el rango algo asi ---> suma = suma + notas[j];  despues que salga del for sacas la media algo asi  resultado = suma/3;

Comment: No tengo ningún error, pero tengo esa parte de código para introducir las notas, pero ahora no se como coger cada nota para sumarla y dividirla entre 3

Comment: Vale ya lo tengo, no se como no había caído, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Codigo

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int cantidad = 3;
        int[] notas = new int[cantidad];

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nIntroduzca notas correspondientes (1-10)");

        for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {

            int nota;

            do {

                System.out.print("Nota " + (i + 1) + " : ");

                nota = teclado.nextInt();

                if (!(nota >= 1 && nota <= 10)) {
                    System.out.println("\nLa notas deben ir del 1 al 10, introduzca de nuevo");
                }

            } while (!(nota >= 1 && nota <= 10));

            notas[i] = nota;
        }

        System.out.println("La media de las notas es " + calcularMedia(notas));

    }

    public static double calcularMedia(int[] arreglo) {

        double resultado = 0;

        for (int nota : arreglo) {
            resultado += nota;
        }

        return (resultado / arreglo.length);
    }

}
```

---

#### Resultado

```
Introduzca notas correspondientes (1-10)
Nota 1 : 5
Nota 2 : 5
Nota 3 : 5
La media de las notas es 5.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

---

### Explicacion

Hemos creado esta funcion:

```
public static double calcularMedia(int[] arreglo) {

    double resultado = 0;

    for (int nota : arreglo) {
        resultado += nota;
    }

    return (resultado / arreglo.length);
}
```

Cuya utilidad consiste en tomar un arreglo, que **sin importar el tamaño que tenga**, te devolverá el promedio de los elementos del mismo.

Cabe aclarar que la funcion que realiza la media, debe ser de tipo `double` preferiblemente, ya que la media consiste en una *division* y el resultado de la misma puede conllevar el uso de decimales.

Ademas hemos dejados este par de variables:

```
int cantidad = 3;
int[] notas = new int[cantidad];
```

Para dejar tu codigo de modo que si el ejericio te pide ingresar mas de tres notas, solo basta cambiar el valor de `cantidad` por la cantidad de notas que necesitas calcular. Y no necesitaras realizar mas cambios en el codigo.

---

### [Ver Ejemplo](https://tio.run/##XVBBTsMwEDynr1j1lKgiFBAXov6AnnqscljiJbg4dmRvihDK24MTHOJ0L5ZnZkcze8Er3pmW9EV8DkPbvSlZQaXQOTii1PCz2SQBdYzsn6uRAhrPpSe2UtfnEtDWLhulECaRmqFCzVKggAM8FSvKr2jD6Dyj6QtGZBaXReQyic770uuevUMSgIdb4HEGwiwOp2/H1OSm47z1YVnpdPuK0JCQCILAFw1RyMEWdj60qjqF9jgq0onKspAp6cO7Pogw/ks3m38t0VqqlVnfJugtuU4xCuOz7@PW78bCuD8Fg5fYBKJJFoPdYdJGR@4jP0vcWQ3por@fPXNFuuaPrPjv1w/DLw)

Answer (score 0):

Una manera mas sencilla de realizar dicho ejercicio, (la propuesta de Ivan Botero es correcta) seria utilizar una variable `contador` que vaya acumulando las notas. Después utilizar la variable `media` para asignarle como valor, la variable `contador` entre 3.

El código quedaría así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        int notas[] = new int[3];
        int media = 0;
        int contador = 0;       
        Scanner tecla = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nIntroduca las notas correspondientes(1-10)");         

        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {               

            do{
                System.out.print("Nota "+(j+1)+" : ");
                notas[j]=tecla.nextInt();   
                if(notas[j]<1 || notas[j]>10)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nLa notas deben ir del 1 al 10, introduzca de nuevo");
                }
                contador += notas[j];
            }while(notas[j]<1 || notas[j]>10);                          
        }           

        media = contador / 3 ;
        System.out.print("\nLa media de las notas es: "+media);     
    }
}
```